# How to detect and not display unavaible youtube videos in html

Tags: iframe, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-iframe-api

**I am using youtube data api v3 and youtube embed iframe for my project.But some of the videos are unavaible.How can I detect this videos and not display in html? I'm using js and vue framework.** [Video blocked by channel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e7wym.png)[Video is not avaible in your country](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1cor1.png)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the code you have.

Comment: Could you provide the video ids of the pictures you shared?